# Is it true that jQuery 1.6.2 automatically evals on the json response?

Tags: jquery, json

I thought `result` will be a json object if the response header includes `application/json`,

```
$.get(...,function(result){
    //here result is a json object
});
```

But today I tried a earlier version of jQuery,found result is a `string`.

So is it true that jQuery 1.6 automatically converts the `result` to object(`eval("("+result+")")`) for me?

**UPDATE**

Here's the related header,but it turns out I have to eval it manually:

```
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
Content-Type    application/json; charset=EUC-JP
```

**UPDATE**

No doubt now,it's confirmed.

Comment: According to the docs at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ it shouldn't: _The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of the response._

Comment: The key point is **when** it starts to behave like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this feature doesn't exist in `jquery 1.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

If the server sets the `Content-Type: application/json` response header, jQuery automatically evals the result, and this is true even for older versions.

Comment: I've pasted the related header above,but actually I need to do eval manually.The jquery version is 1.3.2